# What is causing a product to be listed twice in an order, when the customer puts it in the cart once?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

When a customer adds a product to their cart, and then checks out, I get an order report and they get a notification with one of the products listed twice - once as the real price, and the duplicate time as free.

[image: Screenshot of duplicate listing in Magento]

These are three products that are set up as options/flavors of one main product (Gummies).  The customer selects the flavor of gummy, and adds it to their cart, then checksout, and after the order goes through, the order report shows 2 of the same product - one free, one the correct price.  This is confusing for the customer, since they didn't ever order 2 of the duplicate item.

What might be causing this problem?  And, how might I go about fixing it?

Comment: Hi! Are there any extension installed that could alter products functionality?

Comment: I'm using extensions, but none that I think would impact product functionality.  Here's a screenshot of all extensions I'm using:  http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cb4bwzz63

Comment: Are you able to test this while disabling any of the extensions related to order management or shipping? I've seen extensions that listen for order events and will manipulate the cart as part of its feature. In doing so, behavior could be erratic, especially if the extension was built to suit a specific release of Magento. Verify that you still have this issue with 3rd party extensions disabled and we can help from there.